# setting path for generation txt file in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a user interface for myself that is generating a text file, but I want to set a location where I want in my local system. Like I want to save as button in my page when I am giving the location.I am using file upload tag but it takes just upload the files only.

```
enter code here
     <html>
       <body>
        <table width="60%">
        <tr>
            <td>Browser name</td>
            <td><select name="browser" id="browser" class="form-control-sm" required>
          <option id="select" value="">--Select--</option>
          <option id="gc" value="google_chrome">Google Chrome</option>
          <option id="mf" value="mozilla_firefox">Mozilla Firefox</option>
          <option id="op" value="opera">Opera</option>
          </select></td>
          </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>Instance name</td><td><input type="text" id="instancename" class="form-control-sm" name="instance" required></td>
           </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>file Path</td><td><input type="file" id="config" class="form-control-sm" name="config" required></td>
       </tr>
      </table>

       <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
       </body>
      </html>



       <?php
                if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
                 $browser = $_POST['browser'];
                 $instance = $_POST['instance'];


                  $output = "browsername=".$browser."\r\ninstancename=".$instance.;


              $file = fopen("exemple.txt","w+");
              fwrite($file,$output);
              fclose($file); 
              print_r(error_get_last());


              echo realpath("example.txt");
```

}
?>

Comment: if it is not understandable please ask me

Comment: i want just what i am generated file is there i have to save in local system under desired location

Comment: Or simply how to take a folder path of the saving document